# Google Apps Script problems running as different user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am having problems with script execution from within my company's Google Workspace account.

I am the developer and I have no problem executing any of the scripts with my account; all my scripts run all the way to the end.

Now, there is this one script through which I present the user with a form in a sidebar for him/her to input some data, and then I do some stuff with that data. As mentioned, no problems for me. However, when I try to run it as another person from the company (which isn't just another editor but the superadmin account for the company's Google Workspace), after the initial script permission-granting dialogues are done and dusted, the script only runs halfway through and hangs. It actually gets the sidebar up, allows the user to input data and also to submit some data (I need to check if it submits all of the data). I know for a fact that some of the data does get submitted since one of the things the script does is fill up a particular cell with the data of one of the inputted fields, but it hangs there forever... How could that happen? I thought it might be a problem with the HTMLService, but as some of the inputted data does go through and gets added to the right cell..., I'm at a loss.

Has anyone encountered anything alike?

Comment: Have you checked if the same issue happens with incognito mode? Also, could you share the code to try it?

Comment: Hi @Kessy! Thanks so much for your help! I can't believe it actually works in incognito mode! That's great news in a way, though now I have to figure out how to make it work on a normal window... 
Do you still want to see the code?

Comment: Actually, it only works in incognito mode in Chrome, not in Firefox, so that's not the end of it...

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, after I banged my head around for hours, it was a matter of dealing with protected cells.

Even though the script is set to execute as me, as soon as the script attempted to write into a protected cell whenever a different user executed it, and where I had set myself as the only user with write access, it failed.

Thanks go to @Kessy for having a look into it and suggesting a possible way to see the problem.